# How to import multiple taxonomy terms from csv using Feeds

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds, importing-exporting

I have a csv with the following structure:

```
1024    Huwelijk
1024    Communie/Lentefeest
1024    Bedrijfsfeest
1024    Seminarie
1024    Koffietafel
1024    Receptie
1024    Jubileum
1024    Verjaardagsfeest
1024    Doopfeest / Baby borrel
1024    Vergadering
```

1024 is an ID I have linked to a node and want to use to update taxonomy terms.

When I run this importer , only the last Item (vergadering) is checked on the node.

All terms already exist in the vocabulary.

How can I process this so all items are checked on the node?

Answer (score 1):

[Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv)

This module will help you to import the taxonomies in system.

Comment: Can you use this module to import terms on existing nodes?

Comment: No it wont, Considering your title this is the best one to import the taxonomies in system. Will let you know any possibility.

Comment: Just confirm that your term reference field on node has "Number of values" property set to unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the terms into a single row like

```
1024    Bedrijfsfeest, Seminarie, Koffietafel, Receptie
```

Comment: The excel list is huge, is there a way to automatize this?

Comment: I have found a macro which helps me to reorganize the data: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/563615-macro-transpose-based-value.html